ggrepel how to force geom_text_repel to draw a label line between the text label and its respective point?
> dput(d)
structure(list(line = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L), levels = c("plasmid", 
"COLO678_P", "KKU213_P", "C2BBe1_C9", "COLO678_C9", "SW837_C9", 
"NUGC3_C9", "AGS_C9", "GCIY_C9", "X769P_C9", "RCCFG2_C9", "HUCCT1_C9", 
"KKU213_C9", "HAP1_C9", "MCF10A_C9"), class = "factor"), sorted_gene_pair = c("RXRA_RXRG", 
"HDAC4_HDAC5", "CSNK2A1_CSNK2A3", "NR2E1_PTEN", "STK3_STK4", 
"CYB5A_CYB5B", "HSPA2_HSPA8", "TOB1_TOB2", "CCNC_PTEN", "SNX12_SNX3", 
"PTEN_WRN", "CCND1_CCND3", "PPP2R1A_SHC1", "ABCC1_ABCC3", "ASB5_CDKN2A", 
"BNIP3L_CDKN2B", "CDKN2B_MUC5AC", "KLHL9_PTEN", "CDKN2B_TNFRSF10B", 
"CRK_CRKL", "NRBP1_NRBP2", "CEP290_RPL10", "NR2C1_NR2C2", "CCND2_CCND3", 
"CCAR2_PTEN", "GMDS_PTEN", "SMC1A_SMC1B", "IQGAP1_IQGAP2", "RHBDF1_RHBDF2", 
"FHIP2A_FHIP2B", "ASB1_CDKN2A", "IFNA10_RB1", "NEFL_PTEN", "EPHA7_PTEN", 
"TIA1_TIAL1", "MRPL41_PLEK2", "PARD6B_PARD6G", "GTF2F2_PTEN", 
"HSPA2_HSPA8", "NT5E_PTEN", "PTEN_TNFSF11", "PTEN_TNKS", "PTEN_TSHZ1", 
"CDKN2A_CYSLTR2", "CDKN2A_UBE2F", "RARS1_RARS2", "DNAJC15_DNAJC19", 
"CDKN2B_FDFT1", "DLC1_PTEN", "AKT1_AKT3", "CDKN2A_STK25", "AKT1_AKT3", 
"CDKN2A_NMUR1", "CSNK2A1_CSNK2A3", "IFNA16_PRKN", "CDKN2A_INPP5D", 
"CACNG2_CACNG3", "NFATC1_PTEN", "FOXO1_PTEN", "PRDM1_PTEN", "LOXL2_PTEN", 
"CDIPT_TSTD1", "CCNC_PTEN", "STK24_STK25", "ATAD1_KLHL9", "ABCC1_ABCC3", 
"FBXO25_FBXO32", "GRIN3A_GRIN3B", "ASB18_IFNA8", "CREBBP_EP300", 
"RAD23A_RAD23B", "CEP290_RPL10", "EAF1_EAF2", "TUBA1C_TUBA3C", 
"BANP_PTEN", "FBXO25_RB1", "CDKN2B_CRYAB", "MX1_NT5E", "SAP30_SAP30L", 
"HMGCS1_HMGCS2", "HTR1E_MX1", "CHD1_PTEN", "NIPA2_NIPAL1", "MYH4_MYH6", 
"CDKN2A_MACROD2", "CDKN2A_DUSP4", "IFNA2_PDCD1", "DOCK5_PTEN", 
"CSNK2A1_CSNK2A2", "NUMB_NUMBL", "DIMT1_TFB1M", "ATP1A2_ATP1A4", 
"HK2_HKDC1", "FLNA_FLNC", "CDKN2A_NEFM", "DMWD_WDR20", "CLEC4C_CLEC6A", 
"CDKN2B_PRKN", "CDKN2B_NFATC1", "GRIA2_GRIA3"), normalised_gi_score = c(-0.278770216314704, 
0.342249665523598, 0.660997906602496, 0.942685688601364, 1.07968867708917, 
-1.24856967257752, -0.531833062384577, -0.353987625977806, -0.159423576257236, 
0.409924337113917, 0.691142877843985, -0.899601572046119, -0.779028031671698, 
-0.122509875918777, 0.318200706565636, 0.610889747579626, 0.89796530722066, 
1.12163639755395, 1.36753911177607, -2.99684027376794, -1.93206796875661, 
-1.12097030496128, -0.0930945307406517, 0.0418978048855012, 0.327531606711299, 
-1.16990630587463, -0.997485395276296, -0.408032522901682, -0.173901132446537, 
0.565511677080373, 0.636154784462457, 0.694298419328759, 0.982726714847064, 
1.09918042598289, -1.44463091431326, -1.13746806551196, -1.05621625213901, 
-0.689033105928117, -0.241015547269287, 0.628916361479691, 0.904706982925307, 
1.06584391934823, 1.10995443461768, 1.25079781260332, 1.30095545292242, 
-1.19349505280131, -0.901935839892544, 0.303535955551251, 0.306668260510352, 
1.11887159969018, 1.13628751350697, -0.0356280417787755, 0.217262098099652, 
0.337829569123904, 0.419038951704566, 0.51551211807676, 0.521088208936359, 
0.826971903130793, 1.07937381402565, 1.1543472589458, 1.17055577397093, 
-0.482618731483533, -0.216704950497212, -0.160771009909653, 0.011083574179474, 
0.252309521189895, 0.308270180721431, 0.410407912246551, 0.527396120403485, 
-2.82386864819177, -1.97308489183933, -1.1923258818619, -0.431778959487181, 
-0.424848717973553, -0.215974062996029, 0.341125510476642, 0.40019204838467, 
0.570204407305244, -0.831564396969325, -0.726339910307656, -0.178313405877569, 
0.0142575726874437, 0.0872717590229456, 0.391954875182679, 0.584458830861475, 
0.660079021334363, 0.673986571343958, 1.29249998789928, -2.28134295256182, 
-1.39743978904808, -1.04568387842432, -0.602523344765886, -0.067634984122524, 
0.00397814533065774, 0.293760335712564, 0.416921691016984, 0.468195590010868, 
0.607727275744795, 0.609313969061023, 0.620710114914487), neglogfdr = c(0.453324122107798, 
1.21386395156149, 1.76229379895274, 6.31279789438457, 7.04198781348702, 
3.48253821068604, 1.97886259666303, 0.590414658283615, 0.46434857159993, 
1.14001563782258, 4.54047555759468, 3.05965514495563, 2.13267969826318, 
0.179235887209434, 0.738624480733352, 2.8819501459697, 10.0113989432396, 
6.72281494739941, 10.7567493721685, 15.209105393971, 6.32702859530908, 
4.07930421634025, 0.126955643851482, 0.0923985991715759, 1.28833697946996, 
3.29305877231342, 2.04893282879283, 0.988919332215387, 0.299029429741288, 
1.93292085259831, 2.71024766361634, 2.14117344097359, 7.31049872207915, 
5.59434876498246, 3.27426688783056, 4.18934838671954, 3.23857037221296, 
1.2140069049073, 0.464886767942717, 1.78303564632591, 6.7119430199595, 
5.37019372576537, 7.20043780485619, 3.54528132695541, 6.84428231483913, 
1.70405029288769, 1.39696053162319, 0.668250165422391, 0.494666133436141, 
3.62699346368552, 3.80415068195506, 0.0418942377382991, 0.452053925335558, 
1.19632417353151, 0.739905344902212, 2.82253974229965, 1.6700233498553, 
5.63395868516799, 8.10720954685877, 8.36221478456031, 10.075629600371, 
0.538687615184315, 0.286897717820867, 0.386567840722634, 0.0323971676737839, 
0.661083513915805, 0.896760426922034, 1.76382500698883, 1.55688207945998, 
4.98094726730976, 3.56208111230702, 2.70920883984603, 0.673835483056965, 
0.568602131020346, 0.293306468287876, 0.562146637634021, 1.12638801756608, 
1.58436374163208, 2.87147722268725, 1.76491688275053, 0.372939343770784, 
0.0736911375230091, 0.290387154930043, 2.2053468004523, 2.05053936934909, 
3.9380198603646, 4.00549439333802, 11.2553678354067, 7.33345001713305, 
5.67545630479698, 3.83771683579129, 1.44342818278279, 0.093423831815816, 
0.024595627371412, 0.898849052414252, 1.83341699019596, 2.34903527506412, 
4.09403278578544, 4.44708406126265, 2.92796590124633), sig = c("nonsignificant", 
"nonsignificant", "nonsignificant", "significant", "significant", 
"significant", "nonsignificant", "nonsignificant", "nonsignificant", 
"nonsignificant", "significant", "significant", "significant", 
"nonsignificant", "nonsignificant", "significant", "significant", 
"significant", "significant", "significant", "significant", "significant", 
"nonsignificant", "nonsignificant", "nonsignificant", "significant", 
"significant", "nonsignificant", "nonsignificant", "nonsignificant", 
"significant", "significant", "significant", "significant", "significant", 
"significant", "significant", "nonsignificant", "nonsignificant", 
"nonsignificant", "significant", "significant", "significant", 
"significant", "significant", "nonsignificant", "nonsignificant", 
"nonsignificant", "nonsignificant", "significant", "significant", 
"nonsignificant", "nonsignificant", "nonsignificant", "nonsignificant", 
"significant", "nonsignificant", "significant", "significant", 
"significant", "significant", "nonsignificant", "nonsignificant", 
"nonsignificant", "nonsignificant", "nonsignificant", "nonsignificant", 
"nonsignificant", "nonsignificant", "significant", "significant", 
"significant", "nonsignificant", "nonsignificant", "nonsignificant", 
"nonsignificant", "nonsignificant", "nonsignificant", "significant", 
"nonsignificant", "nonsignificant", "nonsignificant", "nonsignificant", 
"significant", "significant", "significant", "significant", "significant", 
"significant", "significant", "significant", "nonsignificant", 
"nonsignificant", "nonsignificant", "nonsignificant", "nonsignificant", 
"significant", "significant", "significant", "significant"), 
    cell_type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L), levels = c("Colon", "Stomach", "Kidney", "Biliary tract", 
    "Myeloid", "Breast\nNon-cancer"), class = "factor"), direction_gi_score = c("negative interaction", 
    "positive interaction", "positive interaction", "positive interaction", 
    "positive interaction", "negative interaction", "negative interaction", 
    "negative interaction", "negative interaction", "positive interaction", 
    "positive interaction", "negative interaction", "negative interaction", 
    "negative interaction", "positive interaction", "positive interaction", 
    "positive interaction", "positive interaction", "positive interaction", 
    "negative interaction", "negative interaction", "negative interaction", 
    "negative interaction", "positive interaction", "positive interaction", 
    "negative interaction", "negative interaction", "negative interaction", 
    "negative interaction", "positive interaction", "positive interaction", 
    "positive interaction", "positive interaction", "positive interaction", 
    "negative interaction", "negative interaction", "negative interaction", 
    "negative interaction", "negative interaction", "positive interaction", 
    "positive interaction", "positive interaction", "positive interaction", 
    "positive interaction", "positive interaction", "negative interaction", 
    "negative interaction", "positive interaction", "positive interaction", 
    "positive interaction", "positive interaction", "negative interaction", 
    "positive interaction", "positive interaction", "positive interaction", 
    "positive interaction", "positive interaction", "positive interaction", 
    "positive interaction", "positive interaction", "positive interaction", 
    "negative interaction", "negative interaction", "negative interaction", 
    "positive interaction", "positive interaction", "positive interaction", 
    "positive interaction", "positive interaction", "negative interaction", 
    "negative interaction", "negative interaction", "negative interaction", 
    "negative interaction", "negative interaction", "positive interaction", 
    "positive interaction", "positive interaction", "negative interaction", 
    "negative interaction", "negative interaction", "positive interaction", 
    "positive interaction", "positive interaction", "positive interaction", 
    "positive interaction", "positive interaction", "positive interaction", 
    "negative interaction", "negative interaction", "negative interaction", 
    "negative interaction", "negative interaction", "positive interaction", 
    "positive interaction", "positive interaction", "positive interaction", 
    "positive interaction", "positive interaction", "positive interaction"
    ), mean_obs_slfc = c(-0.308082800742622, -0.0750669169531065, 
    -0.0952729143185069, -0.0114395160204061, 0.0229142679687041, 
    -0.803449398698846, -0.971893329227218, -0.224523951435549, 
    -0.70623929146998, 0.0360352958166854, 0.137098949537266, 
    -0.721100928485189, -0.822451256622301, -0.384274131341571, 
    -0.0215019369387432, 0.107762220607702, 0.0162869946652652, 
    0.162287661846136, 0.186053228405021, -1.12744006315866, 
    -1.35202819192059, -0.953764730211623, -0.392378489245787, 
    -0.091170561890553, -0.112888543928862, -1.38240188193851, 
    -1.12225790839503, -0.210749436008001, -0.458854806251842, 
    -0.0129389724146667, -0.187262618884025, 0.158045095944445, 
    -0.0338393577883383, -0.0672227389850132, -0.548658915664394, 
    -0.893317689119132, -1.03050741835404, -0.699163822322675, 
    -0.494365874204525, 0.35853503747824, 0.457185216092409, 
    0.43121760839374, 0.5097425382126, 0.523949473857158, 0.594264389769149, 
    -0.997244439824443, -0.612496633971725, -0.240532718293763, 
    -0.136377598939022, 0.00482614866763637, 0.026531540629545, 
    -0.289616380683185, -0.127429758457226, -0.0359252484240891, 
    -0.0157766840204872, -0.0576090210979508, -0.194320923405098, 
    0.247348177005441, 0.204275362349342, 0.251866858724303, 
    0.291608835471078, -1.2870460905279, -0.725263223404041, 
    -0.0802567940327711, -0.109041126402545, -0.285970684682802, 
    -0.00872525311205748, -0.071514735241029, -0.0272545024968005, 
    -1.05928402570391, -1.15174214424169, -1.22570444185762, 
    -1.03607693454901, -0.42810339993979, -0.359172213790937, 
    -0.0312138549702716, -0.0444114829573184, -0.0882371282990616, 
    -0.706605521526781, -1.26110870926067, -0.279758582417054, 
    -0.392810615171514, -0.274284499838913, -0.0971761993868384, 
    -0.00950584235104721, -0.139656223849661, -0.0901188412438667, 
    0.15125022240376, -1.03677474877481, -0.75156217487781, -1.20184228947105, 
    -0.36954563179565, -0.433094455907448, -0.150129478130089, 
    -0.0629442068423258, 0.0271383354979549, -0.0495504751457398, 
    0.0730425195485702, 0.0244530788960859, 0.0163343965870552
    ), rank = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
    9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
    8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
    12L)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -100L), groups = structure(list(line = structure(4:15, levels = c("plasmid", 
"COLO678_P", "KKU213_P", "C2BBe1_C9", "COLO678_C9", "SW837_C9", 
"NUGC3_C9", "AGS_C9", "GCIY_C9", "X769P_C9", "RCCFG2_C9", "HUCCT1_C9", 
"KKU213_C9", "HAP1_C9", "MCF10A_C9"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(
    1:5, 6:11, 12:19, 20:25, 26:34, 35:45, 46:51, 52:61, 62:69, 
    70:78, 79:88, 89:100), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -12L), .drop = TRUE))

Right now I am getting geom text labels but it is unclear which point they are labelling as points are very close together. How can I force to draw a line between the label and the point? Thanks!
plot <- d %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = line, y = normalised_gi_score, label = sorted_gene_pair, alpha = sig)) +
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(seed = 2), aes(color = mean_obs_slfc)) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c('significant' = 1, 'nonsignificant' = 0.3)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme_manuscript(base_size = 16) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = normalised_gi_score_threshold, linetype = 'dashed', color = 'black') +
  geom_hline(yintercept = -normalised_gi_score_threshold, linetype = 'dashed', color = 'black') +
  labs(x = 'Cell line', y = 'Normalised GI score', color = 'Observed DKO LFC', alpha = 'Statistically significant') +
  scale_color_gradient2(
    low = "red", mid = "grey70", high = "blue",
    midpoint = 0,  space = "Lab", 
    limits = c(-2, 2), breaks = seq(-2, 2, 1), 
    guide = guide_colourbar(ticks.colour = "black", frame.colour = 'black', frame.linewidth = 1/.pt, title.position = "top", title.hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_text(colour = "black", angle = 0),
        strip.placement = "outside") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-6, 6), breaks = seq(-6, 6, 2)) +
  facet_grid(~ cell_type, scales = 'free_x', space = 'free_x', switch = 'x') +
  geom_text_repel(
    aes(label = if_else(rank == 1 | (line == 'MCF10A_C9' & rank == 931), sorted_gene_pair, "")),
    position = position_jitter(seed = 2)
  )

Thanks for your help with this! Much appreciated.

What package is theme_manuscript from? I can only find it in a github package which depends on defunct / archived packages. Please include all library calls necessary to run your code and only include the minimal code to reproduce your problem. Thanks.

theme_manuscript is a custom function to adjust font size - please just delete the line from the code

The point is that you are asking the question and therefore the onus is on you to ensure anyone who tries your code can run it on their machine. You can [edit] your question at any time to add the library calls and remove any non-essential code that will cause difficulties for folks trying to help you here (the geom_hline calls won't run either because you haven't provided the normalised_gi_score_threshold object in your question). That's why a [mre] is important on SO. Currently your code is neither minimal nor reproducible.

geom_text_repel(
    aes(
      label = if_else(
        rank == 1 | (line == 'MCF10A_C9' & rank == 931), 
        sorted_gene_pair, 
        ""
        ),
    ),
    #position = position_jitter(seed = 2),
    force = 1,
    min.segment.length = 0, 
    nudge_y = 1,
    arrow = arrow(type = 'open', length = unit(.2, 'cm')),
  )


NB: the only bit that seems to be strictly necessary for this is the min.segment.length=0, the rest just makes it look nicer otherwise (and is also probably a good idea)
